# Multimedia file retrieval structure

Tags: data-structures, multimedia, stripping

How can we design a file retrieval structure - for a data structure that provides mapping of the file blocks to disk blocks, for simple and staggered striping of multimedia data?

Answer (score 0):

The file blocks can be mapped to the disk blocks by maintaining an Array of File blocks which maps to the location on the Disk Blocks. This technique is used for the mapping blocks of file different disk blocks. Every file is mapped on to the starting address of the disk block. The disk blocks maintain another data structure of Linked list type, which at the end of each block stores address of the next disk block for the retrieval of the multimedia data by simple or staggered striping of multimedia data. This data structure can then be used for the retrieval by simple and staggered striping as it makes it easy to locate a file on different disks using the data structure.

By having this type of data structure, we map the retrieval of a single file stored on multiple disk blocks by the multimedia server. This helps the server provide distributed retrieval of a file from multiple disks.